# How do you parse in TileMapObject from TiledMapEditor using Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I'm trying to parse in TileMapObjects from an object layer from the Tiled map I have created with Tiled map editor using the libgdx framework. I have already successfully parsed in other types of map objects such as RectangleMapObjects using the following code:

```
bouncyPlatforms = Array<BouncyPlatforms>()
        for (`object` in map.layers.get("bouncyPlatformLayer").objects.getByType(RectangleMapObject::class.java)) {
            val rect = `object`.rectangle
            bouncyPlatforms.add(BouncyPlatforms(screen, rect.x / 100, rect.y / 100))
        }
```

However, when I try to parse in a TileMapObject with the following code:

```
foregroundImages = Array<ForegroundEnvironment>()
        for(`object` in map.layers.get("foregroundLayer").objects.getByType(TiledMapTileMapObject::class.java)) {
            foregroundImages.add(ForegroundEnvironment(screen, 1f, 1f))  //(1,1) used for (x,y) while learning how to load TileMapObjects. Positioning still needs to be done
        }
```

I am met with the following error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: map.layers.get("foregroundLayer")
>   must not be null.

I have 10 TileMapObjects in the "foregroundLayer" so either I am not referring to them correctly or the program is not able to detect that they are there. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you add your tmx file to the question?

Comment: The exception message indicates you don't have a layer named `foregroundLayer`. I'd check and make sure you are using the exact name (case matters) from the tmx file